# how to simplify combinatioral map using CGAL

Tags: c++, graphics, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to simplify or edge collapse a mesh read from .off file as a combinatorial map using CGAL

After searching all I found is Surface_mesh_simplification , 
but I want simplification as a combinatorial map not as a polyhedral surface

I appreciate any help or useful links .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surface_mesh_simplification is able to simply any model of the MutableFaceGraph and HalfedgeListGraph concepts (as said [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html)).

Linear cell complex is a model of (cf. [here](https://cgal.geometryfactory.com/CGAL/doc/master/BGL/group__PkgBGLTraits.html)).

You can start from the example given [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Surface_mesh_simplification/examples/Surface_mesh_simplification/edge_collapse_linear_cell_complex.cpp).

Guillaume

Comment: thanks a lot , I'm already tried the suggested example but there is something wrong , it 'sn't simplify the polygon 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615381/simplify-combinatorial-map-using-cgal