# simplify combinatorial map using CGAL

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, computational-geometry, cgal

I want to simplify or edge collapse a mesh read from .off file as a combinatorial map using CGAL

```
 std::ifstream ifile(fileName.toStdString().c_str());
     if (ifile)
     {
        CGAL::load_off(lcc, ifile);
        lcc.display_characteristics(std::cout)<<", is_valid="<<CGAL::is_valid(lcc)<<std::endl;

     }
  namespace SMS = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification ;

    SMS::Count_stop_predicate<LCC> stop(lcc.number_of_halfedges()/2 - 1);

 int r = SMS::edge_collapse
   (lcc
    ,stop
    ,CGAL::parameters::halfedge_index_map(get(CGAL::halfedge_index, lcc))
             .vertex_index_map(get(boost::vertex_index, lcc))
             .get_cost(SMS::Edge_length_cost<LCC>())
   .get_placement(SMS::Midpoint_placement<LCC>())
    );

    std::cout << "\nFinished...\n" << r << " edges removed.\n"
               << (lcc.number_of_darts()/2) << " final edges.\n" ;

     lcc.display_characteristics(std::cout)<<", is_valid="<<CGAL::is_valid(lcc)<<std::endl;
```

**the output :**

```
    #Darts=16674, #0-cells=2775, #1-cells=8337, #2-cells=5558, #ccs=1, is_valid=1
Finished...
0 edges removed.
8337 final edges.
    #Darts=16674, #0-cells=2775, #1-cells=8337, #2-cells=5558, #ccs=1, is_valid=1
```

the method do nothing , I tried more than .off file and it's preview it properly but it cannot simplify it 
I appreciate any help .

Comment: Try to change the stop predicate parameter or use another predicate (read the doc).

Comment: @gdamiand I tried 
 SMS::Count_stop_predicate<LCC> stop(1000);
but it'sn't working

Comment: Try more... I just ran the example given here https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Surface_mesh_simplification/examples/Surface_mesh_simplification/edge_collapse_linear_cell_complex.cpp and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example given [here](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/master/Surface_mesh_simplification/examples/Surface_mesh_simplification/edge_collapse_linear_cell_complex.cpp), it works perfectly.

Comment: thank you I found the problem , I used read_off instead of load_off , it's solves the problem
Have you any Idea about storing the removed edges to insert them again ?

Comment: See https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/classEdgeCollapseSimplificationVisitor.html; you can define your own functor to store the list of collapsed edges. But this is not enough, you also need to store additional information (incident vertices, position of points...)

Comment: Is there a CGAL function used to get (incident vertices, position of points...)?